# Using slider component as video's trackbar and volume control

Tags: guidelines

Do you guys think it is ok (usability wise) to use the same slider component design as video trackbar and volume control?

Answer (score 2):

If they look the same it is obviously a mistake, but you can still use the same slider design if their graduations are different: 0:00 and the total video duration for the trackbar, a muted loudspeaker and a full volume speaker for the volume control.

Another way to distinguish them is to have the volume control vertically and popping up, as it is often seen that way.

Comment: What if i wanna put another slider on the main screen for example , a playrate slider. do you still think it is still appropriate to use the same slider design?

Comment: Well that starts to be crowded! You can still do it but differentiate them even more. Their size is a good way: the video trackbar must be the longest and the two others must remain short. A playrate slider is usually centered (normal speed in the middle) so this is a point of differentiation. Why don't you show us how your slider component looks like, it may help give more advice.

Comment: i would like to, but i dun have enough rep to attach the img here :P

Comment: Put you image on an image sharing website and put the link here.

Answer (score 0):

In that application it's mostly ok, because volume is the short and time the long one, most users would probably get along without any symbols or labels at all.

To improve obviousness, you could use the "bar triangle" that's common for sound level.

Generally, I find sliders a painful interface for seeking in a long video (say, over 30 minutes), especially if the video stream is not very seek friendly (takes time to update, can seek only to sparse key frames, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mart (I would comment if I had enough rep).

We have learned that we turn the volume up or down; and that we go forwards or backwards in a video. So using the orientation as a distinction would help.